# В чем разница компонентов старый и новый sale.order.ajax?

Tags: javascript, битрикс

Доброго времени суток. Ребята у меня пред до мной стоит задача, изменить default шаблон sale.order.ajax, под свои требования. В чем разница старого который был написан на php и нового который на js, не считая ajax? Смогу ли я сделать свои задачи на старом шаблоне ?

Элементарная задача:
1) Создать новый блок Кому? и туда загрузить новые свойства тип строка 3 поля. 
Заранее спасибо. Буду благодарен если прикрепите ссылки на полезную практическую информацию по order.ajax.

2) Я видел сайт в точь точь похожий функционал, смогу ли я скопировать js код и использовать для своего компонента.
  2.1) https://www.tochkacvetov.ru/ - sale.order.ajax
  2.2) http://store.dildiny.kz/ - sale.order.ajax

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Разница в функционале. Новый компонент пошаговый, старый был одношаговым. Просто скопировать js вы не сможете. Гораздо лучше изучить новый шаблон.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию!